# How can i secure my flutter app source code?

Tags: flutter

I am new to flutter and I am creating a flutter mobile application, I am worrying **if anyone get my source code** they can able to replicate my app.

So is there anyway in flutter so even if someone got an application source code they cant able to run the application, like I am expecting that there is a **customized secure encrypted file**, so even if someone got the source code without that customized secure encrypted file they cannot run the application or any other solution to achieve this.

Eg) In my dot net project we import some **customized package file** in order to run the application. Without that package file even if anyone got our source code they cant build/run the solution. Like wise is there anything in flutter?